# Flutter I══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn flutter and I can't seem to get an asset image to load.

I keep receiving a '══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE' error.

See below, my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home()
));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carole Baskin...'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('images/bitch.jpg'),
          ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Click'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
```

Folder Structure: [[image: Images folder]]

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Hey @JamesBeckett, do you have the images directory in your flutter project ?

Comment: @RandomGuru yes

Comment: run pub get to update what you have in your pubspec @James Beckett

Comment: @JamesBeckett: Could you please add the screenshot of your folder structure where the image is placed. Seems like the issue is with your image name (probably)

Comment: @RandomGuru pub get/upgrade doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @MidhunMP Screenshot added to question

Comment: Post a picture of your images folder @JamesBeckett

Comment: @JamesBeckett The folder structure seems fine, do a pub get and re-run your app (not hot reload or hot re-start)

Comment: run flutter clean @JamesBeckett

Comment: Still no luck! This is driving me insane!

Comment: You didn't post what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Try invalidate cache and restart on your Android Studio IDE to solve this error.

I added screenshots of how to do that below:

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to work if I use a different image! Thanks for your help!